# Type hinting breaks PHP class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm encountering this issue.
I have set up a class like this:

```
 <?php

class CalendarTable {
    private $pdo;   
    private $table;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, string $table) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->table = $table;

    }



    public function get_next_event_id() {
           [...]
    }



}
```

But then, when I try to use the class and pass both $pdo and $table, it doesn't work.

If I remove the "***string***" type hinting from (PDO $pdo, ***string*** $table), it works. I am passing a normal string, I have no clue why it's not working (html page breaks). Any idea?

Code using the class:

```
<?php
            $calendar = new CalendarTable($pdo,'calendar');
```

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: Primitive type hinting is PHP7+ only

Comment: I have figured it out as well, dumb question. Still thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Here's the reason why it's not working:

> Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type.
>   Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.
>   "String" type hinting has been reintroduced with PHP 7.0. I am, using  5.4.45, that's why it doesn't work.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Comment: Since PHP7 it is supported! And actually every older version is EOL so you should be running a version that supports it or you are living dangerously :D
This being the "current" source of information: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: I am trying to develop an amateur website, it turns out the free hosting I  am using is set on PHP 5.4.45. I'll switch to a more up-to-date version!
 Thanks for the tip.